# Noninertial frame-rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, inertial-frames, rotational-kinematics

$$de_2=[\cos(d\theta_1)e_2+\sin(d\theta_1)e_3]-e_2=[e_2+d\theta_1e_3]-e_2=d\theta_1e_3$$

I can't see the intuition behind this from [here](http://www.astro.uwo.ca/~houde/courses/PDF%20files/physics350/Noninertial_frames.pdf).

Shouldn't the change in $e_2$ be just this $$de_2=\cos(d\theta_1)e_2-e_2~?$$ Why do we need the $e_3$ component?

Comment: I think your question will attract more attention if you describe the problem in more detail. Few of us will be enthusiastic about reading a pdf just so we can understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For  finite $\theta_1$ :

\begin{equation}
\Delta\mathbf{e}_{2}=\mathbf{e}'_{2}-\mathbf{e}_{2}=\cos\theta_1\,\mathbf{e}_{2}-\mathbf{e}_{2}+\sin\theta_1\,\mathbf{e}_{3}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}

For  infinitesimal  $\mathrm{d}\theta_1$ :

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{d}\mathbf{e}_{2}=\mathbf{e}'_{2}-\mathbf{e}_{2}=\underbrace{\cos\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}}_{\approx\;1}\,\mathbf{e}_{2}-\mathbf{e}_{2}+\underbrace{\sin\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}}_{\approx \;\mathrm{d}\theta_{1}}\,\mathbf{e}_{3}= \mathrm{d}\theta_{1}\,\mathbf{e}_{3}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}

Comment: @ Frobenius. Its a question which has nothing do to with the answer. How you managed to draw such a nice diagram? Can you please let me know what software you are using? What i noticed, you answers to some extent based on well drawn diagrams with mathematics.

Comment: @mas : GeoGebra. It's free. You can edit equations written in LaTeX inside the program (not inserted from outside)